# How would you take a filename as a command line argument and JSON parse that file in .net?

Tags: .net, mono

Say I have a file abc.json and I want to pass the location of that file into a dotnet program, then read that file in and parse it.

Command line would be like this:

```
myprog.exe -f path/to/abc.json
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing using C#, then your main should look something like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

If you are developing using VB.Net, then in your main you can add this line

```
Dim args() As String = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
```

Either way, the args array will contain each item in the command arguments list seperated by spaces:

```
args[0]="-f"
args[1]="path/to/abc.json"
```

After that, you can open the file and read the lines using the standard .Net (System.IO) functions.

```
    Using sw As New System.IO.StreamReader(filename)
        Do
            Dim line As String = sw.ReadLine()
            ProcessLine(line)
        Loop While (Not sw.EndOfStream)
    End Using
```